In Tikz, why the odd arrow head?
I'm getting an odd arrow head on the right node.

The question is, who's controlling that looped arrow on node C as it is ignoring the path style. I see that I can add \tikzset{>={Latex[length=2mm]}} to the start of my document but that globally changes all my arrows in my rather large document. How does one force all arrows in a single diagram to be consistent?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 

\title{tempTikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.25cm, line width=1pt,%
                  every path/.style={-{Latex[scale=1.0]}}]
  
    \begin{scope} [minimum width = 1.0cm, minimum height=1.0cm]
      \node[draw] (s_0)                {a};
      \node[draw] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {b};
      \node[draw] (s_2) [right=of s_1] {c};
    \end{scope}
  
    \draw   (s_0) edge              node[above] {$x\bowtie c$} (s_1);
    \draw   (s_1) edge              node[above] {$\bot$}       (s_2);
    \draw   (s_2) edge [loop right] node[right] {$\bot$}       (s_2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


welcome! you can use >={Latex[length=2mm]} in the options for the tikzpicture instead of globally.

Any thoughts on why that particular path was odd? I'm looking for some intuition on the hierarchy of the graphics. That path seems to belong to a different master's formatting.

You are setting an arrow to every path, but when you say loop right this is an alias for a set of parameters that includes a default arrow, which supersedes your every path. Changing the default arrow as in @cfr's answer solves the problem.

To be exact, there is an every loop which defaults to ->,shorten >=1pt  installed, see https://tikz.dev/library-edges#pgf./tikz/every:loop

You can just apply the option to the particular tikzpicture:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\title{tempTikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.25cm, line width=1pt,%
  every path/.style={-{Latex[scale=1.0]}},>={Latex[length=2mm]}]

  \begin{scope} [minimum width = 1.0cm, minimum height=1.0cm]
    \node[draw] (s_0)                {a};
    \node[draw] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {b};
    \node[draw] (s_2) [right=of s_1] {c};
  \end{scope}

  \draw   (s_0) edge              node[above] {$x\bowtie c$} (s_1);
  \draw   (s_1) edge              node[above] {$\bot$}       (s_2);
  \draw   (s_2) edge [loop right] node[right] {$\bot$}       (s_2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

